# How to eliminate the word "Chapter" from the header using "book" documentclass

Tags: header-footer, chapters, book-design, books

I'm writing an user manual for an application I made, and I'm using the book documentclass. I was able to eliminate the word "Chapter" from both the begining of the chapter and the table of contents, so it only shows the number and the chapter name. BUT I don't know how to remove it from the page header as well.
A MWE (maybe not so minimal...) is as follows:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish]{layout}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage[bottom=2.5cm,top=3cm,left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm,footnotesep=0.5cm]{geometry} % ,showframe
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \Huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
        \fi
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
    }
}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \Huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
        \fi
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
    }
}
\makeatother
\addtolength{\footnotesep}{2.5mm}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textbf{\arabic{footnote}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    %\includegraphics[width=6cm]{pics/logo.png}
    \par\vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\LARGE Company's shortname\par}
    \par\vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\LARGE Manual de Usuario \par}
    \par\vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\Large Company's name \par}
    \vfill
    {\scshape My name ;) \par}
    \today \par
\end{titlepage}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

%\include{./TeX_files/intro}
\mainmatter
%\include{./TeX_files/primeros_pasos}
%\include{./TeX_files/cap_actas}
%\include{./TeX_files/cap_fotos}
\chapter{This is a chapter}
Some filler text here... \footnote{This is the footnote.}

\backmatter
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\end{document}
```

The result of this would be as in the images below:

[image: Table of Contents]
[image: Begining of Chapter]
[image: Problem I'm facing]

Thanks in advance! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify also `\chaptermark`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[
  bottom=2.5cm,
  top=3cm,
  left=1.8cm,
  right=1.8cm,
  footnotesep=0.5cm,
%  showframe,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the test

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \Huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
        \fi
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
    }
}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \Huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
        \fi
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
    }
}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markright{%
    \MakeUppercase{%
      \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
          %\@chapapp \ %
          \thechapter. \ %
        \fi
      \fi
      #1%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\addtolength{\footnotesep}{2.5mm}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textbf{\arabic{footnote}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    %\includegraphics[width=6cm]{pics/logo.png}
    \par\vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\LARGE Company's shortname\par}
    \par\vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\LARGE Manual de Usuario \par}
    \par\vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\Large Company's name \par}
    \vfill
    {\scshape My name ;) \par}
    \today \par
\end{titlepage}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{This is a chapter}
Some filler text here... \footnote{This is the footnote.}

\lipsum[1-15]

\backmatter
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\end{document}
```

I have left the part where `\@chapapp` is inserted by the default command.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the following in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newlength\mywidth
\settowidth{\mywidth}{\ }
\def\@chapapp{\hspace*{-\mywidth}}
\makeatother
```

Now your MWE can be updated as:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish]{layout}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage[bottom=2.5cm,top=3cm,left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm,footnotesep=0.5cm]{geometry} % ,showframe
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newlength\mywidth
\settowidth{\mywidth}{\ }
\def\@chapapp{\hspace*{-\mywidth}}
\makeatother
\addtolength{\footnotesep}{2.5mm}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textbf{\arabic{footnote}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    %\includegraphics[width=6cm]{pics/logo.png}
    \par\vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\LARGE Company's shortname\par}
    \par\vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\LARGE Manual de Usuario \par}
    \par\vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\Large Company's name \par}
    \vfill
    {\scshape My name ;) \par}
    \today \par
\end{titlepage}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

%\include{./TeX_files/intro}
\mainmatter
%\include{./TeX_files/primeros_pasos}
%\include{./TeX_files/cap_actas}
%\include{./TeX_files/cap_fotos}
\chapter{This is a chapter}
Some filler text here... \footnote{This is the footnote.}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext


\backmatter
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\end{document}
```

Note: I have added `\blindtext` command from `blindtext` package to get some dummy text. You can also use the definitions that were used in your MWE if Chapter number and chapter title to print in two lines.

Output:

[image]